# XSLT List Transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm currently working on an XSL script that transforms the following xml into an ordered list. Please refere to the input and output sample below. I'm using XSLT 2.0 by the way.

```
**Input:**
<xml>
    <numberedList>1. Number List 1</numberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 1</unnumberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 2</unnumberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 3</unnumberedList>
    <numberedList>2. Number List 2</numberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 1</unnumberedList>
    <numberedList>3. Number List 3</numberedList>
</xml>

**Output:**
<html>
<ol>
    <li>1. Number List 1</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Child List 1</li>
            <li>Child List 2</li>
            <li>Child List 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2. Number List 2</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Child List 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3. Number List 3</li>
</ol>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried using <xsl:for-each-group> with group-adjacent but it won't do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempted improvement on Dimitre's XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
   <ol>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()">
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="self::numberedList">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <li><ul><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></ul></li>
         </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
   </ol>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="numberedList|unnumberedList">
  <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I could have written it this way if I didn't want to produce "if-less" code. I think that eliminating explicit conditionals (even though one sometimes has to use modes to achieve this) contributes to readability and understandability. Of course, my approach may be considered extreme, and this solution shows that when used sparingly, conditionals may produce "natural" solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solutions guys! I appreciate it. All of them would work wonderfully but I prefer the shortest solution.

Answer (score 2):

**I. A slightly shorter XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kUlist" match="unnumberedList"
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                        [not(self::unnumberedList)][1]
                   )"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="numberedList[1]" mode="first"/>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="numberedList" mode="first">
   <ol>
     <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::*"/>
   </ol>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <li><xsl:apply-templates /></li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "unnumberedList
      [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::unnumberedList])]">
   <li>
     <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="inUList" select=
           "key('kUlist', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[1]))"/>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="inUList">
   <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="unnumberedList"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<xml>
    <numberedList>1. Number List 1</numberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 1</unnumberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 2</unnumberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 3</unnumberedList>
    <numberedList>2. Number List 2</numberedList>
    <unnumberedList>Child List 1</unnumberedList>
    <numberedList>3. Number List 3</numberedList>
</xml>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<html>
   <ol>
      <li>1. Number List 1</li>
      <li>
         <ul>
            <li>Child List 1</li>
            <li>Child List 2</li>
            <li>Child List 3</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>2. Number List 2</li>
      <li>
         <ul>
            <li>Child List 1</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>3. Number List 3</li>
   </ol>
</html>
```

---

**II. An XSLT 2.0 solution -- 30% shorter than I.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <html>
   <ol>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
   </ol>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="#default inUList">
  <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "unnumberedList[preceding-sibling::*[1][not(self::unnumberedList)]]">
  <li>
   <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inUList" select="current-group()"/>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="unnumberedList"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <ol>
      <li>1. Number List 1</li>
      <li>
         <ul>
            <li>Child List 1</li>
            <li>Child List 2</li>
            <li>Child List 3</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>2. Number List 2</li>
      <li>
         <ul>
            <li>Child List 1</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>3. Number List 3</li>
   </ol>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Undoubtedly this can be done easier, but try the following.
Explanation: it's self-explanatory :-)
Note that this will also work in XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <html>
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="numberedList[1]"/>
            </ol>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="numberedList">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="unnumberedList [local-name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = 'numberedList']">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </li>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1] [local-name() = 'unnumberedList']"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::numberedList[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="unnumberedList [local-name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = 'unnumberedList']">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1] [local-name() = 'unnumberedList']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <ol>
        <li>1. Number List 1</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Child List 1</li>
                <li>Child List 2</li>
                <li>Child List 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>2. Number List 2</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Child List 1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>3. Number List 3</li>
    </ol>
</html>
```